# Отображение времени Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, сервер

Хоть убей не пойму как включить отображение времени в панели резидентных программ!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не помню, как конкретно это делается на Windows Server 2003. А обычно на XP это просто правый клик по панели, раздел - область уведомлений, опция - отображать часы.![опции][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpKgM.png

Comment: Благодарю, так оно и делается, а то я тоже затупил :-)